# MYSQL query greater than AND lesser than

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named  character_level:

```
level                  experience
  1                         0
  2                         998
  3                         2994
  4                         5988
```

and so on.

I have another table user_Character¨

```
ID                   character_current_xp
1                          150
2                           35
```

to check if level must be changed I do this:

```
$xp = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT character_current_xp FROM user_character WHERE ID = '$currentUser'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($xp))
  {
        $current_xp = $row['character_current_xp'];
  }
$lvl2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT level FROM character_level WHERE experience <= $current_xp order by experience desc limit 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($lvl2))
  {
  $level_after = $row['level'];
  }



if(isset($_POST['accept_xp'])){ //with this i check ressults
        $setxp = "UPDATE user_character SET character_current_xp = character_current_xp+100, character_current_lvl = $level_after  WHERE ID = $currentUser"; 

        mysqli_query($con, $setxp);
        mysqli_close($con);
        header('Location: account.php');
    }
```

Problem is wheither i use `<= $current_xp order by experience desc limit 1` weither `>= $current_xp order by experience desc` im still off by one level.

Anyone can shoot me anything?
Thanks in advance.
Chris

Comment: I test your second select  with experience <= $current_xp order by experience desc limit 1and it tells me a user with 150 has still level 1 and 998 has level 2 . That seems right to me. What did you expect?

Comment: This looks OK to me, are you sure it's not because you're adding the 100XP after checking the level? If someone had 900 XP at the top of your script, they would get level 1, but by the end they would have 1000 XP, which should now be level 2 but they would still be at level 1.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to update current_character_level with $level_after dynamically? Maybe triggers or anything?

Comment: In your `$lvl2` query just do `where experience <= $current_xp+100` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's something:

```
SELECT l.level
  FROM user_character c
  JOIN character_level l
    ON l.experience <= c.character_current_xp
 WHERE ID = '$currentUser'
 ORDER 
    BY experience DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i want to use use suggestion as automated task with generate. but it showing me an error for SELECT¨. I am trying the below code:                                                     
 ```ALTER TABLE user_character MODIFY COLUMN character_current_lvl BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SELECT l.level FROM user_character c JOIN character_level l ON l.experience <= c.character_current_xp ORDER BY experience DESC LIMIT 1) STORED```                                                                any suggestions? many thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, don't do this.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to generate character_current_lvl values?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with simply executing a query whenever that information is required.

Comment: With character_gold you can train str. But trains continue even if character_gold is 0 and as a result character_gold becomes negative:                                                                                  ```if(isset($_POST['train_strength'])){ 
    $trainstrength = "UPDATE user_character SET strength_trains = strength_trains + 1, trained_strength = trained_strength +1, character_gold = character_gold - $gold_to_next_strength WHERE ID = $currentUser"; 
 mysqli_query($con, $trainstrength);
    mysqli_close($con);
 header('Location: account.php');
}``` how can I prevent that?

Comment: If you have a new question, I think you're best off asking one.